# Google Analytics custom dimensions and goal conversions

Tags: universal-analytics

Having built out custom dimensions within Universal Analytics, the hope was to be able to associate conversions taking place with these custom dimensions but alas it is not operating as such.

Does anyone know why that would be the case?

Comment: Hi, this is off topic and should be asked in the Webmaster forum, as it is not related to coding.

Comment: Why isn't it related to coding?  We have the code in place but the dimension only gets associated with page level metrics (sessions, pageviews, avg time on site) but not with any conversions or events???

Comment: SO is a forum strictly (but not thoroughly enforced) for coding related issues (eg. syntax, coding practices, etc.). Generally if there's no code on your post, and it's related to analytics, then it should be posted to Webmasters or other appropriate forum. Please have a look at the posting guidelines if you are not familiar with them. Thanks! By the way, I am not a mod, just a regular user like you.